# Is there a way to create a zip file from multiple files on google drive with the API?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api, drive

The Google Drive web interface allows you to download a single .zip file if you download a directory. However, I find no way to do that with the API. Is it possible to create a multi file zip on drive with the API?

Update: Tanakie's code works! This is great! However, I'm only able to get it working in my personal account. I have two G-Suite admin accounts and I get the error:

"Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.

Please check the address and try again."

I have confirmed this works fine in multiple free personal google accounts.
Any idea why it will not work when using a paid google account?

------- UPDATE ------

If you get the "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time" error, wait a day, that error will fix itself.

Here's my final solution only with a POST. Pretty much as Tanaike says below.

Google Script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var zipFileName = e.parameter.zipFileName
  var fileIds = e.parameter.ids.split(",");
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(zipping(fileIds, zipFileName));
}

function zipping(fileIds, zipfilename) {
  var blobs = [];
  var mimeInf = [];
  var accesstoken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  fileIds.forEach(function(fileID) {
      try {
          var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
          var mime = file.getMimeType();
          var name = file.getName();
      } catch (er) {
          return er
      }
      var blob;
      if (mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.script") {
          blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/feeds/download/export?id=" + fileID + "&format=json", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accesstoken},
            muteHttpExceptions: true
          }).getBlob().setName(name);
      } else if (~mime.indexOf('google-apps')) {
          mimeInf =
              mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" ? ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", name + ".xlsx"] : mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.document" ? ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", name + ".docx"] : mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation" ? ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", name + ".pptx"] : ["application/pdf", name + ".pdf"];
          blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileID + "/export?mimeType=" + mimeInf[0], {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accesstoken},
              muteHttpExceptions: true
          }).getBlob().setName(mimeInf[1]);
      } else {
          blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileID + "?alt=media", {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accesstoken},
              muteHttpExceptions: true
          }).getBlob().setName(name);
      }
      blobs.push(blob);
  });
  var zip = Utilities.zip(blobs, zipfilename);
  var driveFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("zipFiles").next();
  return driveFolder.createFile(zip).getId();
}
```

php code to call it:

```
$url       = 'https://script.google.com/a/domain.com/macros/s/### script id ####/exec';
$googleIDs = array();
foreach($documents AS $document){
    $googleIDs[] = $document->google_file_id;
}
$data['zipFileName'] = date('c') . ".zip";
$data['ids']         = join(',', $googleIDs);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "Content-type: multipart/form-data" ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch); // This returns the Google file ID of the zip file.
curl_close($ch);
```

HOWEVER, As in my comment below, this was a useless, futile exercise as Google limits files created by scripts to 10M. I'm off to find a solution that does not depend on Google... Wish I'd known that before I started.

Comment: BEWARE!!! I did get this working. However, since Google limits files created by scripts to 10M, it's pretty much useless.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I should have firstly ask you about the size you use. I apologize it.

Comment: Can I ask you about the size of one file? If that is less than 10MB, how about creating zip files by the unit of 10MB?

Comment: A single group of files could easily be many hundreds of meg. Some much larger. Splitting into 10M files is not practical. Most individual files are less than 10M but in that case the user will download that file without zipping. 
I'm working with a vary large amount of data.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this workaround?

Unfortunately, there are no APIs for directly creating a zip file from outside in Google APIs. But I think that there is a workaround. There is `zip()` method of Class Utilities in Google Apps Script (GAS). And there is Web Apps as a service for using GAS from outside. I think that what you want to do can be achieved by combining them.

#### Flow :

1. Create a GAS script for creating zip files using `zip()` method of Class Utilities.
2. Deploy the script as Web Apps.
3. You can launch the script from outside using GET and POST method of your applications. When you access Web Apps, also you can give some parameters and data.

#### Reference :

- [zip() method in Class Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#zip(BlobSource))
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

How about a following sample script? This is a simple sample script for creating a zip file for files in a folder.

- When Google Docs of Spreadsheet, Document and Slide are included in the folder, they are converted to Excel, Word and Powerpont format, respectively.
- When standalone scripts are included in a folder, they are converted to text data.
- Other types (images, text data and so son) are not converted.

These are the same to the web interface.

#### In order to use this script

Please do the following flow.

1. Copy and paste the sample script to the script editor. And save it.
2. Deploy Web Apps

   - On script editor

     - Publish -> Deploy as web app
     - At "Project version", create new version.
     - At "Execute the app as:", select "Me".
     - At "Who has access to the app:", select "Anyone, even anonymous".
     - Click Deploy button.
3. Test the Web Apps using curl command as follows.

   - If you can get the file ID of created zip file, it means that the script works.

#### Sample script :

```
function doGet(e) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(e.parameter.folderid).getFiles();
  var fileIds = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    fileIds.push(files.next().getId());
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(zipping(fileIds));
}

function zipping(fileIds) {
  var zipfilename = "sample.zip";
  var blobs = [];
  var mimeInf = [];
  var accesstoken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  fileIds.forEach(function(e) {
      try {
          var file = DriveApp.getFileById(e);
          var mime = file.getMimeType();
          var name = file.getName();
      } catch (er) {
          return er
      }
      var blob;
      if (mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.script") {
          blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/feeds/download/export?id=" + e + "&format=json", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accesstoken},
            muteHttpExceptions: true
          }).getBlob().setName(name);
      } else if (~mime.indexOf('google-apps')) {
          mimeInf =
              mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" ? ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", name + ".xlsx"] : mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.document" ? ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", name + ".docx"] : mime == "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation" ? ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", name + ".pptx"] : ["application/pdf", name + ".pdf"];
          blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e + "/export?mimeType=" + mimeInf[0], {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accesstoken},
              muteHttpExceptions: true
          }).getBlob().setName(mimeInf[1]);
      } else {
          blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e + "?alt=media", {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accesstoken},
              muteHttpExceptions: true
          }).getBlob().setName(name);
      }
      blobs.push(blob);
  });
  var zip = Utilities.zip(blobs, zipfilename);
  return DriveApp.createFile(zip).getId();
}
```

#### Sample curl command :

```
curl -L "https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec?folderid=### folder ID ###"
```

#### Note :

- If you modified the script, please redeploy Web Apps as a new version. By this, the latest script is reflected.
- As a limitation of the sample script, this sample script checks only files in a folder. If you want to retrieve folders in a folder, you can see the sample script [here](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/8e9b6fd667efcb483c9c742da9cd4e19).
- After you got the file ID of created ZIP file, you can download it using Drive API as you know.

If this was useful for you, I'm glad.

Comment: This is a great idea! It will be a while before I can try it but I'll come back and accept this answer if I can get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim Duncklee Welcome. Thank you for the comments. If you need a sample script, feel free to tell me.

Comment: If you don't mind, a sample script would be fantastic! Thanks!

Comment: @Tim Duncklee I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tim Duncklee If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: I had one of my guys give it a try and could not get it to work. I will give it a try myself again in a few days and let you know if I am successful. Thank you Tanaike!

Comment: @Tim Duncklee I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I have confirmed that in my environment, this sample script works. Please be assured. In my experience, one of important points for using Web Apps is to redeploy Web Apps as new version when the script was modified. I sometimes also forgot it and it troubles me that the script doesn't work.

Comment: This is fantastic! Your script worked first try! Now I am trying to give the script specific file ID's rather than zip an entire folder and having trouble. I am updating my question with the code.

Comment: @Tim Duncklee I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I have 3 questions. 1. Can you confirm whether those file IDs are correct, again? 2. If you want to use the shared files, can you try to test this using your own files without sharing? 3. I cannot understand your situation. I don't know about ``line 2``. Can I ask you about your current whole script?

Comment: I figured the first problem out. Now the issue is getting it to work in a paid G-Suite account. See my edited question.

Comment: I'm waiting on Google support to figure out why this won't run in G-Suite but meanwhile, I do not see how curl can be used as google login and access approval is needed to use the script. Can curl actually be used? I may need to figure out call it with php from API?

Comment: @Tim Duncklee I'm sorry. I have never been a paid user yet. So I could not notice about your situation. I'm so sorry for this. Google API can be used by curl. In my experiences, I have never seen APIs which cannot be used by curl. But about login, I have no experiences yet. I'm sorry in the lack of experience.

Comment: No worries. Thank you so much for getting me this far! I'll figure out the rest of it. :-)

Comment: @Tim Duncklee Thank you, too. If there's anything I can help with, please let me know.

Comment: @Tim Duncklee Recently, since I knew other users under the situation like you, I created a GAS library for zipping files in a folder. If this is useful for you, I'm glad. https://github.com/tanaikech/ZipFolder

Comment: Tanaike, Your code sure helps me! My situation is I need to pass an array of document id's to the script (rather than a folder) and have it create a zip file and return the id of the zip file. I also need to do this with the api. I have it working fine now I'm figuring out how to use the api. :)

Comment: @Tim Duncklee For example, you can use the API like curl sample. 1. Retrieve a file ID of zip file from your custom API using GET method. 2. Download it using Drive API. When your custom API includes password as a query, the security will be higher.