# Download folder from Google Drive with REST API v3

Tags: c#, rest, google-drive-api

I have a simple setup: client-side UI with server-side service.

Client-side is responsible for user interaction between folders/files. And the server is responsible for saving the file(s) provided file `id` and `mimeType`.

Currently, I am able to export google documents, presentations, spreadsheets, drawings as files and any binary format files.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/export

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{0}/export?alt=media&mimeType={1}", fileid, mimeType));
var file = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
/* save file using apropriate method/logic */
```

Now I am trying to download and save folders.

If we take into account that Google folder is treated as another file coupled with Google Drive zipping folder prior to download in the browser. My idea was to use the same `export` endpoint to get Google to return me a zip file.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{folder_id}/export?alt=media&mimeType=application/zip
```

But it is not as simple as that.

```
code: 403
domain: global
reason: fileNotExportable
message: Export only supports Google Docs.
```

After trying a few different mimeTypes and receiving the same error I come to the following conclusions.

- Folder export operation is restricted or not enabled/supported
- I have to access a different endpoint point
- I have to provide additional parameters
- Use correct mimeType value

If there are any Google gurus here can you confirming:

1. If it is possible to export a folder (as zipped file is fine)
2. What is required to achieve this (endpoint/parameter(s)/mimeType)

Answer (score 3):

How about the following workaround?

### 1. Answer for your question

#### Exporting a folder as a zipped file

Unfortunately, using Google APIs, a folder cannot directly exported as a zipped file. When you want to export a folder as a zipped file, for example, how about a following workaround?

- There is zip() method of Class Utilities in Google Apps Script (GAS). And there is Web Apps as a service for using GAS from outside. I think that what you want to do can be achieved by combining them.

  - The detail information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918380/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-zip-file-from-multiple-files-on-google-drive-with-the/46920940#46920940).

#### Downloading a zip file.

Google Docs (Spreadsheet, Document, Slide) can be exported using the endpoint of `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### file ID ###/export`. But files which are not Google Docs like your case cannot be exported using the same endpoint. So please use the endpoint of `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### file ID ###?alt=media`. In this case, there is no parameter of the mimeType.

#### References :

- [zip() method in Class Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#zip(BlobSource))
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Endpoints for Downloading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

### 2. Flow of this workaround

1. By sending folder ID using GET method to Web Apps, create a zipped file of the folder, and return the file ID of zipped file.
2. Download the zipped file by Drive API.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: your suggested workaround should do the trick. I wasn't aware of GAS until your post. Coincidentally the code suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918380/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-zip-file-from-multiple-files-on-google-drive-with-the/46920940#46920940 is almost the same as my .Net service. Cheers.

Comment: Just a couple of other things if you don't mind me asking. 1) What would happen if the zip with the same name already exists? Will the script just overwrite it or throw an exception? 2) What level of Authorisation is required? I am working on a web application that will be accessed by many users whom will download their files. 3) Are there any limitation to be aware of? File size or permissions?

Comment: @iiminov Thank you for your response. I can answer your questions. A1: [My this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918380/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-zip-file-from-multiple-files-on-google-drive-with-the/46920940#46920940) uses one filename as a sample. But the filename can be given by query of GET method. So you can use filenames you want. A2: When you will use Web Apps, you can set freely. If you create a zip file using GET method, you can also set a password in the query. A3: You can set the permission freely using GAS. Is these answer useful for achieving what you want?

Comment: I jumped the gun a little when I posted my comments. The script in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918380/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-zip-file-from-multiple-files-on-google-drive-with-the/46920940#46920940) is perfect. All I did is change how ``zipfilename`` is generated.

Comment: I wasn't clear how and when the permissions get set until I published my script just a few minutes ago. All you get are two options: 1) How the script is run (against web apps or against the user that is accessing the script) and 2) Who can access the script (only you or anyone with internet connection). Simple enough.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you also get the url link to the script after it is published.

Comment: How does this ``var accesstoken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();`` line of code work exactly? I call my script in .Net service so the user doesn't get any UI. As far as the user is concerned they just click the Download link and they get success/error message. My ``httpClient`` includes the ``Authorization`` header with the access token. Should I bother extracting it from ``doGet(e)``?

Comment: @iiminov I'm sorry for the inconvenience. A1: You can see the curl sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918380/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-zip-file-from-multiple-files-on-google-drive-with-the/46920940#46920940). You can set the query parameter to the URL. [The query parameter can be retrieved at ``doGet(e)`` in GAS side.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters)

Comment: @iiminov A2: You can run the script using GET request. A3: The permission can be set when [deploys Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions). A4: The URL of web apps can be retrieved from [Deploying a script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app).

Comment: Haha, this just couldn't be any more timely. Just run the script and logged the response error I got: ``Authorization needed`` and ``Error parsing NaN value. Path '', line 0, position 0.``. Back to the drawing board for me.

Comment: @iiminov A5: ``ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`` is only used at GAS side. In this case, you can use API (in this case, it is Drive API.) without OAuth2 process. In my answer, Web Apps is used for only creating zip files. When users download the zip file, your script is required to do. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @iiminov I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I don't know about your current situation. If you can do, can you share your GAS script on your script editor? When you cannot show it here, you can send it using e-mail.

Comment: @iiminov Recently, since I knew other users under the situation like you, I created a GAS library for zipping files in a folder. If this is useful for you, I'm glad. https://github.com/tanaikech/ZipFolder