# Bulk exporting google docs as .zipped html files

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm basically wanting the same output as I would get for exporting a single file as html, zipped; but for a folder full of files.

Ideally there's some built-in function I don't know about.  I looked through the gdocs python api, but I didn't see anything that really looked like a solution to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: no built in function. You'll need to do it by hand

Comment: @Toph As a workaround, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918380/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-zip-file-from-multiple-files-on-google-drive-with-the/46920940#46920940

Comment: @Tanaike I'll play around w/ this over the weekend and let you know!